# Dynamically adding control to master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with dynamically loading control's into master page's ContentPlaceHolder.

Name of the ContentPlaceHolder and path of the UserControl is loaded from db and send to this little code:

> Control c = this.Page.LoadControl(uc-path-from-db);
>   this.Page.Master.FindControl(cph-name-from-db).Controls.Add(c);

When I run it, I get this error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any code blocks (<% %>) in the <head> element of the Master page?

Comment: No markups whatsoever.
When I googled for this problem, and I ran to the posts that say to look for the code blocks in head element, but I don't have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not totally clear without your markup, but it is telling you that you can't Add the control in there because some of your markup contains a <% ... %> block which tells ASP.NET to execute whatever is in there to create your markup. Try removing your <% ... %> block and it should let you Add the control. Or post your markup for a more complete answer.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't have any markup.
I have just added the control, compiled the project, run the project, expected UserControl to be added without any data and got that error.
I am totally puzzled about the error message.

Comment: So there is no code blocks in your master page, page or user control?

Comment: I don't know how to answer.
I saw code block in a page, but that seems not to interfere with the loading of controls because loading works with that code block and I am not quite sure what I did because I did a lot of stuff trying to make it work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of Web Project you're working with, you have to be sure to <%@ Register%> your UserControl on both the MasterPage you're loading it to, and the Page you're loading it from. If you're working with a web *site* and not a web *application* it compiles each page into it's on little assembly and won't reference the usercontrol's assembly unless it sees that Reference tag in the markup.

I'm not 100% on this, but it's worth a look.

Comment: I am using web application and I call that code from BaseClass.
I tried to call it from page_load of the default page and it loads, but without any data even if I put some text inside the control.